# SQL server Merge rows based on a key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following input:

```
Country ID      city     country        capital
----------------------------------------------
1               Barcelona  NULL           NULL
1               NULL       Spain          NULL
1               NULL       NULL           Madrid
2               Marseille  NULL           NULL
2               NULL       France         NULL
2               NULL       NULL           Paris
```

the output should be:

```
Country ID      city     country        capital
----------------------------------------------
1               Barcelona  Spain         Madrid
2               Marseille  France        Paris
```

Based on the Country ID I would like to merge the rows with an sql request

Comment: GROUP BY, MAX()

Comment: The query that generates your original data probably has a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this, Using `group by` and `max` will give you the desired result.

```
SELECT country_id,
       MAX(city) AS city,
       MAX(country) AS country,
       MAX(capital) AS capital
FROM   table
GROUP  BY country_id
```